# Glassfish 4 works in AIX server?

Tags: glassfish, web-deployment, aix

I'd like to ask if you know if Glassfish 4 is supported in IBM AIX systems.. I installed Glassfish3, but when deploying my app im having these errors That I cannot workaround:

[#|2015-01-23T14:46:37.543+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=179;_ThreadName=Thread-11;|Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer load method
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: IIOP Protocol Manager initialization failed.  Possible cause is that ORB is not available in this container

java.lang.RuntimeException: Orb initialization erorr

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.rcm.ResourceAttributes not present

Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.rcm.ResourceAttributes not presente

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.rcm.ResourceAttributes

Under Windows I deploy without a problema...

Any suggestion is welcome thank you.